# Javascript null coalescing help, how can I incorporate a threshold value? a = b || c but if b > d, choose c

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator

I want to assign a value to a variable in javascript

```
var a = b || c; //however if b > 200 choose c
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
var a = (b && b <= 200) ? b : c;
```

Thanks for any tips or advice. Just trying to write this as cleanly as possible.

Comment: I think what you have is just fine. Seems simple enough to me.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Nope! Hcabnettek was right to ask, because it can be simplified even more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = b;
if(b == undefined || b > 200){
    a = c;
}
```

Comment: should comparison against undefined always use === ?

Comment: The correct way to check for an undefined value in JS would be: `typeof b == "undefined"`

Comment: @Deleteman: That's an option, but it isn't *"the correct way"*.

Comment: @Deleteman No. That is not true. The expression `x === undefined` is true iff and x evaluates to `undefined` and thus sufficient. (This answer uses `==` which is a little more accepting, though). `typeof` is only needed if it is not known if the variable `b` has "been defined" (global property or with `var`), which is another icky issue entirely.

Comment: @pst: there is, of course, the shady area of redefining `undefined` to mean something else.  But you could always use `(b == void 0)`.  If you're not using strict equality, though, you might as well just use `b` alone.

Comment: @Andy E I program only under a sane set of assumptions ;-) (Only on very, very rare occasions do I actually explicitly test for undefined.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it even more:

```
var a = b<=200 && b || c;
```

Or, more readable,

```
var a = ( b<=200 && b ) || c;
```

Explanation:

- You can use `&&` to get the first falsy value or, if there isn't any, the last truly one.
- You can use `||` to get the first truly value or, if there isn't any, the last falsy one.

Therefore:

- If `b` is falsy

  Then, `b<=200 && b` is falsy, so `b<=200 && b || c` gives `c`
- If `b` is truly

  - If `b<=200`

    Then, `b<=200 && b` gives `b`, which is truly, so `b<=200 && b || c` gives `b` too.
  - If `b>200`

    Then, `b<=200 && b` gives `false`, which is falsy, so `b<=200 && b || c` gives `c`.

Some tests:

```
100<=200 && 100 || 50      // 100, because 100 is truly and 100<=200
150<=200 && 150 || 50      // 150, because 150 is truly and 150<=200
'150'<=200 && '150' || 50  // '150', because '150' is truly and 150<=200
300<=200 && 300 || 50      // 50, because 300<=200 is false (but 300 is truly)
'abc'<=200 && 'abc' || 50  // 50, because NaN<=200 is false (but 'abc' is truly)
({})<=200 && ({}) || 50    // 50, because NaN<=200 is false (but {} is truly)
false<=200 && false || 50  // 50, because false is falsy (but 0<=200)
null<=200 && null || 50    // 50, because null is falsy (but 0<=200)
''<=200 && '' || 50        // 50, because '' is falsy (but 0<=200)
```

Comment: That'll do it, but readability is horrific.  How about some `()` so we don't have to second-guess ourselves and go lookup JS operator precedence tables ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Well, you're right, with `()` is more readable. But I assumed `||` precence over `&&` in JS is well-known, and I wanted to simplify it the most I could. Anyway, I have added the `()` possibility